# Two tables with one value

Tags: sql-server

[enter image description here][1]can someone please advise on this?

These two tables have the renters name, one is in r.renter.own1 and the other is in t.renter.name

```
Acct  Owner1   Owner2
256   ABC      NULL
478   NULL     FGH
```

What can I do to get it as?

```
Acct  Owner
256   ABC
478   FGH
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8xVW.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select Acct, coalesce(Owner1, Owner2) as Owner
from myTable;
```